# Notation for constant array.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Consider an array whose elements are all the parameter $a$. I can represent it by
$(a_i;i \in [1,8])$, but that doesn't really convey that it is a constant matrix. Does this notation make sense $(a;i \in [1,8])$? Also, this notation is too bulky for my work.  I was wondering what you think of the very concise notation $a_{[1,8]}$ or even $a_{[8]}$. I'd like to generalize this to constant arrays whose elements might be ordered sets.  For  example, $(1,b)_{[1,8]}$ would be an array whose elements are all $(1,b)$.  What do you think?

Comment: In my line of work the all-ones vector shows up often enough that it's common to write $a\cdot\mathbf{1}$. In my context usually the length of the vector is clear, but this is admittedly missing in the notation. If I were forced to clarify, I'd perhaps abuse notation from partitions and write $a\cdot\mathbf{1}^b$. Alternatively, it's common to write sequences in the form $(a_i)_{i=1}^n$. Unfortuantely $(a)_{i=1}^b$ looks a like a typo, but I don't hate $(a)^b$. Of course no matter what shorthand you pick, you'll have to define it somewhere.

Comment: $(a)^b$  might be confused with an exponent.  Wouldn't you put $n$ on the bottom?

Comment: Both choices are in common use to discuss sequences. People also write $(a_i)_{i=1,...,n}$ but there's still the "floating $i$" problem when all $a_i=a$, and you can't eliminate it as easily [I'm not sold on $(a)_{1,...,n}$]

Answer (score 3):

Here's one of mathematics' big secrets - you can use whatever notation you like, as long as it's clearly defined and doesn't cause confusion.

As pointed out in a comment, it is common to use $\mathbf{1}_n$ to represent a vector consisting of $n$ elements that are all equal to 1, so writing $a \mathbf{1}_n$ or $a \cdot \mathbf{1}_n$ would work, but even in a formal mathematical paper it wouldn't be taken for granted and so the author would define it before using it. For example,

> Let $\mathbf{a}_n = a \cdot \mathbf{1}_n = (a, a, \ldots, a)$ be a vector containing $n$ repetitions of the value $a$.

Comment: How would you extend this in an attractive way to a two dimensional array.  Would you replace n with [n,m]?

Comment: Yes, $1_{m,n}$ is standard notation for a matrix of 1s